# able to receive msgs in xmpp in ios but unable to send

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am getting 503 error while sending msgs. I know the reason for this error, that I am missing the resource with the domain.

i.e abcd@domain/resource

I am using only abcd@domain. Now, I do not know ,how to get the resource? Which class holds the value for resource ?

```
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
            [body setStringValue:messageStr];
            NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
            [message addAttributeWithName:@"type"stringValue:@"chat"];
            [message addAttributeWithName:@"to"stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userId]];
```

I have the user id as : abcd@domain but I am missing the resource , as the correct value for the variable userId is abcd@domain/resource and I have no idea how to get resource value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide any resource, generally a random resource(number) is assigned when you login. Try providing a resource when you login. All xmpp login functions have the option of providing the resource while calling the function. Check up with the declaration of the login function provided in your library.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
But I couldnt understand your reply. You mean, I should pass a random number while login i.e with the username, I should also provide the resource like this : abcd@domain/resource(a random number) ?

Or you want to say that I get a number a random number when login is successfully completed and I need to use that number.

Comment: Your general Openfire userid is of the type xyz@domain/resource. Now if you fail to provide a resource, the server assigns a random number to your session i.e your session will be identified as xyz@domain/random_number. So in order to avoid this random number assignment, it is better if you provide a resource which logging in.

Comment: Actually I am using gmail id and it is not like the id in openfire which has resource attached to its id.